# Jquery plugin disappears

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-plugins

I have created a very simple jQuery `.widget` plugin that I am able to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function( $ ) {
        $.fn.widget = function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                let $this = $(this);
                $this.load($this.attr("data-widget-source"), function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        const msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                        $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
            });
        };
    }(jQuery)); 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.widget').widget();
    });
```

But when I try to use it in a code that have been loaded using `.load`, it seems to disappear:

```
$("#mymodal").load("/widget/29/", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status === "success"){                       
        M.FormSelect.init(document.querySelectorAll('select') , {});
        // Redirect submit event
        $("#slot_create_form").submit(function(e) {
           ajax_submit(e)
               .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                   console.log("Slot from widget Form  data received: ");
                   console.log(data);
                   $('.widget').widget(); // Here fails 

           }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                   console.log("Form ajax error received: ");
                   console.log(errorThrown);
           });
   });
}
```

It fails with an error

> TypeError: $(...).widget is not a function

Comment: The primary way plugins disappear is if the jQuery library is being included on the page more than once.

Comment: @Taplar That was exactly what was happening. Can you put your comment as response so I can  select it .

Comment: I can't really answer the question with that, as it's more of a comment.  If you want to describe the issue fully and show how you fixed it, you could answer your own question.  Otherwise it might be better if the question were closed/deleted, as on it's own it doesn't really demonstrate the issue, and I'm sure there are other existing questions talking about this issue already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Taplar pointed, The code injected by the `$("#mymodal").load()` was a full THML page that have its own reference to JQuery. This was reloading JQuery and therefore deleting the plugin.

The issue was corrected using a conditional extends in Django and providing a simpler version of the page without scripts:

```
{% extends request.no_frame|yesno:"frameless.html,frame.html,frame.html" %}
```

This request attribute is set by a middleware:

```
class NoFrameMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        if "frame" in request.GET:
            request.no_frame = {'frame': request.GET["frame"].lower() == 'false'}

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        return response
```

And the load call look like this:

```
$("#mymodal").load("/widget/29/?frame=False")
```

The `frame.html` is the regular page and the `frameless.html` is a page without headers or anything that disturbs the host page